# Poynomial rings and algebraically independence

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomial-rings, algebraic-independence

Let $R$ be a ring and let $X_1,\dotsc,X_\ell$ be algebraically independent variables over $R$. Then we have a polynomial ring $R[X_1,\dotsc,X_\ell]$.

I asked my lecturer why we need them to be algebraically independent and he answered that "because you need to make sure that you have a polynomial ring when you adjoint these elements"

I did not fully understand what he meant by "adjoint".

what happens when they are not linearly independent? keep in mind that my English is not my first language.

Comment: What happens if you consider $\mathbb{Z}[2]$? Is that a polynomial ring? What is your definition of a polynomial ring? You can think of adjoining an element to mean that you consider the smallest ring that contains both the original ring an the element that you adjoin. For example $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] = \{ a+ b \sqrt{2} \ : \ a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the meaning of adjoint. $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a polynomial ring. Now it makes sense!